# Hiding app title bar in Android pager

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity

Can anyone tell how to hide the app title bar in Pager fragment. [image]

[image: Android Pager]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar(); // you might need to use getSupportActionBar() based on your project setup
bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Is there any way where i can set this from customized theme ?

Comment: Not sure about that but I think using a base activity where all the others extending from is the best idea. You could also make a static  `setupActionbar(bar)` method in a helper class and call it wherever you need it.

Answer (score 3):

Warren is correct. And if you want to hide it in your theme, you can do it by inheriting from a theme that does not display it:

- For pre-Honeycomb styles:

  ```
  <style name="HiddenActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme">
  </style>
  ```
- For Honeycomb+:

  ```
  <style name="HiddenActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
  </style>
  ```

I personally prefer this method because it frees your classes from UI-related code and can easily be set for every `Activity` by changing the theme of your application in the manifest.