# How to remove the title when launching android app?

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I already remove the title in onCreate() method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}
```

[image: after launched]

The title is not displayed. But still appears when launching the app.

[image: launching the app]

And I can use

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

or put

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

into manifest file because I'm using actionBar. If I did that, the app crashes.

So, my question is, is there any way to remove the title when the app is launching because I am gonna put a splashscreen here. Thanks.

### -----------

**PLEASE NOTICE:**

Thanks for your answers, but I clearly said that I already used `actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`
to hide the title bar of the activity. (as shown in the first picture)
**BUT the title bar still appears in the launching screen (as shown in the second picture.)**

and

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

and

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

would lead to crash launch. This happens after I used actionbar.

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Comment: No, I still have to keep that title bar.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.

Personally, I solved it by replacing my Activity inheritance from
ActionBarActivity to Activity.

Hope this will help someone...

Comment: After 3 hours of searching, this is the best answer, Thanks in advance!

Comment: I agree with Amr SubZero

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your onCreate() method.

//Remove title bar

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

//Remove notification bar

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

this refers to the Activity.

===========

**EDIT:**

if you are using ActionBarSherLock

```
final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: the Window.FEATURE_BO_TILTE would lead to crash when launching the app. And I did setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false) which hides the title bar of the activity but still does not hide it when launching it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be crashing because you are using `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` after `setContentView()`;

Use `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in `onCreate()` of your `Activity` , before `setContentView();` statement.

Comment: I know it should be put after setContentView(), and it lead to crash launching the app.

Answer (score 0):

May be i am repeating the same which all are saying but i just need to confirm it.In manifest file have add the theme like the below which i added as sample or anyother way.

`<application ....
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
         android:largeHeap="true"> ..
</application>`

Just remove all other code related to hide title bar only andonly add this one in the manifest file it works for me.I hope it will work to you too.

Comment: If you use the Tab Fragment example provided by developer.android.com, you will found you can't add this in the manifest file as it will crash... Don't know why

Comment: you just try this link dude.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403488/hiding-app-title-bar-in-android-pager

Answer (score 0):

Nick Butcher and Katherine Kuan wrote a nice Google Plus post about a smoother app launch experience:

https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/VVpjo7KDx4H

However, if you want to be compatible with Android versions below API 14 (for example using AppCompat), the only way I could achieve this is by using a separate launch activity using a theme with no actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `splashscreen` as your main activity and set the theme to

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

create and intent to move your splash screen to your actual main activity

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 ActionBar bar = getActionBar();    
 bar.hide();
```

or

```
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

in *res/values/styles.xml*

**find ...**

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
   <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

**replacing for.**

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

Save and compile...

Answer (score 0):

Put below three line in onCreate Method before setContentview in your activity which want to display full screen

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Answer (score 0):

Hope below lines will help you

```
    getWindow().clearFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN); 
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add full screen theme to that activity in your manifest file:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: Anything else instead of this?

Answer (score -1):

In your AndroidManifest.xml in application tag set your theme to full screen like in below code.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: sorry, as I mentioned, this would lead to crash in the app since I use actionbar.